# Definition of second and QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time, definition

Wikipedia says that the (newly proposed, more rigorous) definition of a second is:

> The second, symbol s, is the SI unit of time. It is defined by taking the fixed numerical value of the caesium frequency ΔνCs, the unperturbed ground-state hyperfine transition frequency of the caesium 133 atom, to be 9192631770 when expressed in the unit Hz, which is equal to s−1.

My question: **at such a tiny scale (the scale of atoms), do the probabalistic laws of quantum mechanics make this definition imprecise in any way?**

Comment: No, in fact the laws of quantum mechanics are the only thing that let this work in the first place. They produce the discrete energy levels that are being transitioned between in the 'hyperfine transition frequency' they talk about.

Comment: What do you mean by imprecise? You certainly can't measure a time interval with perfect precision under this definition, but you can't measure a time interval with perfect precision under *any* definition.

Comment: @Chris I'm obviously not talking about measuring time intervals with perfect precision in the real world. I am talking about the definition of a second, and that's it.

Comment: @AlexAdamov It's not really clear what it means for a definition to be "precise," though. The only thing that comes to mind is "you get a different thing if you measure the same interval twice," but that's a real world precision thing. (And a sense in which this definition is very, very precise, for that matter)

Comment: Probably, if the definition is pressed too far; but it only needs to succeed in being more precise than the other competing definitions.

Comment: I suspect what he's after is whether or not quantum effects make it possible to assign a well-defined meaning to an electromagnetic field oscillation at the given, precise frequency, from a single emitted photon. Now I don't have a lot of knowledge (yet) with quantum field theory, but from what I've heard an EM field loaded with one photon is far from a classical state. Thus his question is that whether there is something measurable or theoretically describable in that case which goes up and down, or _can_ go up and down, 9,192,631,770 times in the interval we call "1 second".

Comment: In classical EM theory, of course there is something: there is a propagating solution where the E- and B- field vector reverse direction this many times. But in QFT, I suspect something different goes on. The single photon case is an eigenstate of the number operator, and I _believe_ (as said my knowledge of QFT is limited and limited to self study at this stage in my physics training) this is NOT an eigenstate of the field operator, which is what would correspond to a "classical EM field". Thus it seems the question of whether something "bobs up and down 9,192,631,770 times" in this QFT

Comment: treatment is not clear or easy to resolve - and for that I'd leave it for someone with the suitable expertise to supply a good answer. That is, in short he's asking what the definition of the frequency of a photon is in these terms, and what exactly, if anything, is vibrating with that frequency.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer you are spot on, my friend.

Answer (score 1):

No, Quantum Mechanics actually makes this definition of a second really precise. The fact that energies of the different states of the Caesium atom are quantised makes it possible to define the exact frequency of this transition (remember $E = h\nu$) so that you can actually have an incredibly precise definition of a second in terms of an integer number times the period $1/\nu$. The hyperfine transition is actually a correction to 'usual Quantum Mechanics' coming from Relativity, so that the energy $E$ is tiny compared with the energies of other excited states. Why they use this particular transition? It must be related with the precision to which it can be measured, but I am not an expert in atomic physics.